# Уместно ли использовать слово "интимный" в качестве "лишенный участия людей вне определенной группы"?

Tags: значение-слов

Например, есть какой-то клуб по интересам, попадание в который затруднительно.

Я пытаюсь понять, можно ли сказать, что среди участников происходит "интимная дискуссия", если "интимная" здесь представлена в значении "скрытая от неучастников" без романтического окраса.

Answer (score 0):

Интим не предлагать. Лучше - конфиденциальность.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]